# write string to postgres via php, hosted on heroku

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku

im using php to take a song request via an ajax, and save it to a postgres db.

everything is in heroku, and I can connect to the db fine using pgadmin

i get the following error - what's the right way to take the string from the GET request and write to db?

> 2014-08-24T01:43:32.062128+00:00 app[web.1]: [Sun Aug 24
>   01:43:31.864706 2014] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 64:tid 139700481152768]
>   [client 10.53.42.218:51189] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP
>   Warning:  pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near
>   "\"\nLINE 1: INSERT INTO songs (request) VALUES(\'song\')\n
>   ^ in /app/songs.php on line 21\n', referer:
>   http://sep21.herokuapp.com/
>
> 2014-08-24T01:43:32.062130+00:00 app[web.1]: [24-Aug-2014 01:43:31]
>   WARNING: [pool www] child 61 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message:
>   PHP Warning:  pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or
>   near "\""
>
> 2014-08-24T01:43:32.062132+00:00 app[web.1]: [24-Aug-2014 01:43:31]
>   WARNING: [pool www] child 61 said into stderr: "LINE 1: INSERT INTO
>   songs (request) VALUES(\'song\')"
>
> 2014-08-24T01:43:32.062134+00:00 app[web.1]: [24-Aug-2014 01:43:31]
>   WARNING: [pool www] child 61 said into stderr: "
>   ^ in /app/songs.php on line 21"

code is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE songs
(
  request character varying[] NOT NULL,
  created bigint,
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "Pk" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "songs.php",
        data: q,
        success: function(resp){
            // console.log(q)
            // console.log(resp)
            try{var song_resp = JSON.parse(resp)}
            catch(err){var song_resp = err}
            // console.log(song_resp)
            // console.log(target)

           if (song_resp.pass == true){
                $("#nice_choice").slideDown(250)
                // $("#nice_choice").css("-webkit-animation-play-state","running")
                // $("#nice_choice").css("-animation-play-state","running")

            }
            else {
                $("#something_wrong").slideDown(250)
                // $("#something_wrong").css("-webkit-animation-play-state","running")
                // $("#something_wrong").css("-animation-play-state","running")
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception){
            $("#something_wrong").slideDown(300)
   //       $("#something_wrong").css("-webkit-animation-play-state","running")
            // $("#something_wrong").css("-animation-play-state","running")
        }

    }); // Ajax Call


<?php
    if ($_GET['q']){
        $song = $_GET["q"];

        $dbconn = pg_connect("host=ec2-54-247-111-1.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 
                    dbname=dbname
                    user=user
                    password=pw")
                or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

        $result = pg_query($dbconn, "INSERT INTO songs (request) VALUES(\'song\')");

        //dump the result object
        if ($result == false) {
            echo false;
        }

        else{
            echo true;
        }

        // Closing connection
        pg_close($dbconn);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pg_query_params` or preferably PDO. Don't roll your own quoting. Ever. [It's just plain wrong](http://bobby-tables.com/) and [the issues are well documented in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

You should preferably be using PDO.

(The immediate problem is that your quoting is wrong. You've used `\'` to escape single quotes where no escaping is required, so the backslashes are preserved in the final query string. You can see that in the error message).